Constructing Cyclic Division Algebras
I'm studying the construction of cyclic division algebras but I don't see how a given example holds.
According to the literature, we start with a finite extension $L$ of a number field $K$ such that Aut$(L/K)\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n=[L:K]$, i.e., a finite cyclic Galois extension. We take a generator $\theta$ of Aut$(L/K)$ and find an element $\gamma$ of $L$ such that for all $\alpha\in L$,
$\begin{align*}\gamma\theta\alpha=\theta(\alpha)\gamma\theta, && (\gamma\theta)^n=\textrm{some }\beta\in L^\times, &&\textrm{and}&& \beta^n\textrm{ is the least power of $\beta$ that is the norm of some element in }L.\end{align*}$
Then $\mathscr{C}(\beta):=\langle L,\gamma\theta\rangle\subseteq\mathrm{M}_n(K)$ is a cyclic division algebra.
When $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$, then Aut$(L/K)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\theta=$ complex conjugation generates Aut$(L/K)$. It is then stated that $\mathscr{C}(1)\cong\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathscr{C}(-1)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i},\mathrm{j},\mathrm{k})$, the rational quaternions.
I can see how $\mathscr{C}(1)\cong\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Let $a+b\mathrm{i},c+d\mathrm{i}\in\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$. Then $(a+b\mathrm{i})(c+d\mathrm{i})=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)\mathrm{i}$ so we can represent multiplication by an element of $L$ as
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$
since
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ac-bd\\ad+bc\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$.
Complex conjugation can be represented by
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$
since
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\-b\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$.
Then $\mathscr{C}(1)=\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle\subseteq\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. One can check that the following holds (note $\overline{(\cdot)}$ is the complex conjugation matrix):

Note
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\-b & -a\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}2a & -2b\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\\
\begin{bmatrix}0 & -c\\c & 0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & c\\c & 0\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\2c & 0\end{bmatrix},\\
\begin{bmatrix}d & 0\\0 & d\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}d & 0\\0 & -d\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 2d\end{bmatrix}.\end{align*}$
These are all in $\mathscr{C}(1)$ so their sum,
$\begin{align*}\begin{bmatrix}2a & -2b\\2c & 2d\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$
is as well. But this is any matrix in $\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ hence $\mathscr{C}(1)=\mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.
I don't see how $\mathscr{C}(-1)$ can even be constructed since we need some $\gamma\in L$ such that $(\gamma\theta)^2=-1$, i.e., some $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$\begin{align*}\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\right)^2=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\end{align*}$
but this would imply we need $a=0$ and $b=\mathrm{i}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. What am I misunderstanding in this construction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Something is definitely fishy here because the quaternion algebra doesn't embed into $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ at all. Other presentations of this material I've seen don't work in terms of an embedding into a matrix algebra at all and just construct the cyclic division algebra by generators and relations. Alternatively maybe you need to find a subalgebra of $M_n(L)$.

Have you tried comparing with standard treatments of quaternion algebras?

@QiaochuYuan Yes, you are right, it is a sub algebra of $M_n(L)$. With this, I recovered the matrix representation of quaternions. Thank you.

FWIW, take a peek at this old answer of mine to see what cyclic division algebras look like. Hmm, you may have figured it out already :-)
